# How to run python and java jar in single bash script?

Tags: java, python, bash

I have some python scripts which crawl data from social media and save their output in .csv format and have some java codes for data cleansing and other purpose.

I want to execute all these python and java script all together with help of bash script.

e.g.

I have two python script lets say :

1  tweet.py
   2. translate.py and one java code say
   3. TextClean.java

I want the execution in order 1 to 3 as output csv from tweet.py will be input for translate.py and so on.

Please suggest me right way to do it.

Regards,

Comment: How have you tried to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Did you do any research on basic command execution and file redirection inside (bash) shell scripts?*

Your question is a bit unclear, so by “input” and “output” I suppose you mean standard input and output.

```sh
python tweet.py > tweet.csv
python translate.py < tweet.csv > translated.csv
java -jar TextClean.jar < translates.csv > cleansed.csv
```

If you don't care about the intermediate results you can chain those commands together in a pipe:

```sh
python tweet.py | python translate.py | java -jar TextClean.jar > cleansed.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bash script:

```
python tweet.py 
python translate.py output.cvs 
java -jar TextClean.jar translate_output.cvs
```